# Does latent classification analysis need a separate verification bias removal? how to perform that?

Tags: statistics, prediction, verification, multiclass-classification, diagnostic-tools

I have clinical data which lacks a golden standard for diagnosis. Instead multiple indices are used with different accuracy. I have transformed the results from these indices to binary for patients having and not having the disease.

This is then used for latent classification analysis. I want to know if I should use all samples for this analysis? or should I divide them and then use remaining samples for validation? Also, will I need to check for verification bias and how do I select a method to do that? How to check the category of each patient for diagnosis after that?

below is tabular form that I used to subject under latent classification analysis (LCA) using poLCA package in R

| Patient_ID | Index 1 | Index2 | Index3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

the results I get are

> Fit for 2 latent classes:
> ========================================================= 
> number of observations: 65 
> number of estimated parameters: 7 
> residual degrees of freedom: 0 
> maximum log-likelihood: -116.6411 \
>
> AIC(2): 247.2821
> BIC(2): 262.5028
> G^2(2): 0.3041395 (Likelihood ratio/deviance statistic) 
> X^2(2): 0.291966 (Chi-square goodness of fit)

what type of graph will make me understand the results better?
Thank you, your help will be appreciated here

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.